# Mongoose - Generate ObjectID for each object before saving document

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, mongoose-schema, objectid

I want generate an ObjectID for each Object present inside my array. The thing is I'm getting the products with a .forEach statement from another server and push them inside my array without a Schema that generates an ObjectID....

Product Schema:

```
const productsSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

  apiKey: String,
  domain: String,
  totalcount: Number,
  totaldone: Number,
  allSKUS: Array,
  allProducts: Array,
  created_at: { type: Date },
  updated_at: { type: Date },

}, { collection: 'products', timestamps: true });

productsSchema.plugin(uniqueValidator);

const Products = mongoose.model('Products', productsSchema);

module.exports = Products;
```

My Code:

```
const newProduct = {

  apiKey: userApiProducts.apiKey,
  domain: userApiProducts.domain,
  totalcount: userApiProducts.totalcount,
  totaldone: userApiProducts.totaldone,
  allSKUS: userApiProducts.allSKUS,
  allProducts: userApiProducts.allProducts // generate ObjectID for each object that gets pushed inside the Array
};

Products.findOneAndUpdate( userApiProducts.domain, newProduct, {upsert:true} , (err, existingProducts) => {
  if (err) { return next(err); }
});
```

Output:

```
// Please Check ADD OBJECT ID HERE comment. This is where i want to generate an unique ObjectID before I push the data. I tried with var id = mongoose.Types.ObjectId(); but i'm afraid it will not be Unique...

{
        "_id" : ObjectId("58780a2c8d94cf6a32cd7530"),
        "domain" : "http://example.com",
        "updatedAt" : ISODate("2017-01-12T23:27:15.465Z"),
        "apiKey" : "nf4fh3attn5ygkq1t",
        "totalcount" : 11,
        "totaldone" : 11,
        "allSKUS" : [
                "Primul",
                "Al doilea",
                "Al treilea"
        ],
        "allProducts" : [
            {
                // ADD OBJECT ID HERE
                "id": 1,
                "sku": "Primul",
                "name": "Primul",
                "status": 1,
                "total_images": 2,
                "media_gallery_entries": [
                    {
                        "id": 1,
                        "media_type": "image",
                        "label": null,
                        "position": 1,
                        "disabled": false,
                        "types": [
                            "image",
                            "small_image",
                            "thumbnail",
                            "swatch_image"
                        ],
                        "file": "/g/r/grafolio_angel_and_devil.png"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 2,
                        "media_type": "image",
                        "label": null,
                        "position": 2,
                        "disabled": false,
                        "types": [],
                        "file": "/g/r/grafolio_angel_and_devil_thumbnail.jpg"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                // ADD OBJECT ID HERE
                "id": 3,
                "sku": "Al doilea",
                "name": "Al doilea",
                "status": 1,
                "total_images": 2,
                "media_gallery_entries": [
                    {
                        "id": 4,
                        "media_type": "image",
                        "label": null,
                        "position": 2,
                        "disabled": false,
                        "types": [],
                        "file": "/g/r/grafolio_angel_and_devil_thumbnail_1.jpg"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 5,
                        "media_type": "image",
                        "label": null,
                        "position": 3,
                        "disabled": false,
                        "types": [],
                        "file": "/b/e/before.png"
                    }
                ]
            }, etc ......
        ],
        "__v" : 0,
        "createdAt" : ISODate("2017-01-12T22:58:52.524Z")
}
```

Is there any way of doing this without having to make a ton of DB Calls? I can't imagine saving like this

```
array.forEach((x)=> {
    Products.save({})
})
```

Hope someone has already worked on something similar and found the perfect solution for this !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to add `ObjectId` automatically, you need to define a separate schema for it and set the `_id` options for the schema as true.

Do the following:

- Change your `productsSchema` as `CatalogueSchema` (for ease of
  understanding).
- Define a new `ProductSchema` for Product (element of allProducts)
- In `CatalogueSchema` define allProducts type as `[Product.schema]`. This will automatically add `_id` (`ObjectId`).

Also, you don't need to add `created_at` and `updated_at` as part of schema when you set timestamps option as true.

**Catalogue Schema**

```
const Product = require('Product_Schema_Module_Path'); // Edit

const CatalogueSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

    apiKey: String,
    domain: String,
    totalcount: Number,
    totaldone: Number,
    allSKUS: Array,
    allProducts: [Product.schema]   
    // Note the change here (Array -> [Product.schema]
  // Creating a separate schema ensures automatic id (ObjectId)

}, { collection: 'catalogue', timestamps: true });

CatalogueSchema.plugin(uniqueValidator);

const Catalogue = mongoose.model('Catalogue', CatalogueSchema);
module.exports = Catalogue;
```

**Product Schema**
(*New schema to ensure adding of ObjectId*)

```
const ProductSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

    id: Number,
    sku: String,
    name: String,
    status: Number,
    total_images: Number,
    media_gallery_entries: Array

}, { _id: true, timestamps: true });  
// _id option is true by default. You can ommit it.
// If _id is set to false, it will not add ObjectId

ProductSchema.plugin(uniqueValidator);

const Product = mongoose.model('Product', ProductSchema);
module.exports = Product;
```

**EDIT** (*Save Products in Catalogue*)

(Also, note that you have to require the ProductSchema module in your CatalogueSchema module)

```
// Map userApiProducts.allProducts to array of Product documents
const products = userApiProducts.allProducts.map(product => {
    return new Product(product);
})

const newProduct = {
    apiKey: userApiProducts.apiKey,
    domain: userApiProducts.domain,
    totalcount: userApiProducts.totalcount,
    totaldone: userApiProducts.totaldone,
    allSKUS: userApiProducts.allSKUS,
    allProducts: products
};

Catalogue
    .findOneAndUpdate({ domain: userApiProducts.domain }, newProduct, { upsert:true } , (err, products) => {
    // Handle error
});
```

Comment: With your method i get [Product.schema] is undefined.. Can you please show me how would you save the ProductsSchema model inside CatalogueSchema ?

Comment: Create separate `CatalogueSchema` and `ProductSchema` in separate modules. Ensure you import `ProductSchema` in `CatalogueSchema`. I have added the code for adding products to catalogue.

Comment: Wow, that actually worked. Thank you so much Santanu !

Comment: Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

To add multiple documents into Mongo you can use `db.collection.insert()`:

- https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.insert/

In Mongoose you can use `Model.insertMany()`:

- http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.insertMany

But keep in mind that when you have one document inside of other document in Mongoose they are not actually stored like that in Mongo. Mongo only stores the IDs of the child documents and not their contents in the parent document - and not even any info on which collection those IDs belong to.

When you use population then Mongoose actually retrieves the relevant documents from the DB in separate requests to Mongo. So, population is a concept of Mongoose. Mongo just stores the IDs, so you need to create the documents first before you can insert the IDs.

The thing that you are trying to do would be easy without using Mongoose. You can store multiple documents in one request in Mongo using your own IDs if you want and you can store another document with an array of those IDs in another request.

Of course however you do it you will get inconsistent state during the operation because Mongo doesn't support transactions.

Comment: I tried insertMany but it does not generate an ObjectID. If i try in the other way by generating the Products in a different Schema and using .find to query for them. In a batch process would that be a bit slower than having a document inside another document ?